# How to force the function implementation should be reference input type rather than value type

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

Please suggest me a way to force the third part implementer should use pass by reference input argument type  rather than using pass by value type. I know using pointer we can achieve this but I dont have an idea how to do it in reference.

### C++:

```
typedef struct data {
    int a;
    int b;
} data;

  //Ambiguous - pass by value
  //void fun(const data value) { // <= Need a way to restrict this type of imp  
  //    std::cout<<value.a<<value.b;
  //}

    // pass by reference 
    void fun(const data& value) {
         std::cout<<value.a<<value.b;
    }

int main() {
    data d;
    d.a = 1; d.b = 2;
    fun(d); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I read this three times and I do not understand the question

Comment: If it's going to be `const` why *not* have it as a reference?

Comment: Is your question "how can I prevent `Data` objects from being passed by value?"

Comment: I'm with the others - it looks like you have what you need already, with `fun( const data & value )`.  What's missing for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question is that you want to provide a header file to third party implementer but you want to restrict them from having a function which takes argument by value.

If you are going to expose your header file as an interface You cannot stop anyone from adding functions to the class. Having said that if you already provide the function taking the reference argument then the third party implementer cannot add same named function which takes argument by value because it will give them a ambiguity error.

Comment: By function declaration in the interface we can force the third party developer to use reference input parameter - this is the suggestion I exactly want...thanks !

Comment: @Sridhar "By function declaration in the interface we can force the third party developer to use reference input parameter"... This is no surpise. If they use _your_ functions, you can force them to pass parameters as you chose in the signature of _your_ functions. But if they create _other_ functions, they can give them any signature they choose (provided that they use available types, of couse - which includes "data").

Answer (score 0):

Let's be clear :

```
// pass by CONSTANT reference 
void fun(const data& value) {
     std::cout<<value.a<<value.b;
}

// pass by reference 
void fun(data& value) {
     std::cout<<value.a<<value.b;
}

// pass by value 
void fun(data value) {
     std::cout<<value.a<<value.b;
}

// pass by pointer 
void fun(data* value) {
     std::cout<<value.a<<value.b;
}
```

If you do not want to pass the input parameter by value, just do not implement the 3rd version.

Comment: For one, your pointer version is wrong, and two, he seems to want to restrict a *third party* from creating functions that pass by value.